# Performance wise... exec(c++) or straight PHP?

Tags: php, c++, performance

Wondering what would be quicker for a mysql open, select, and a generic output of the data:

A) C++ code compiled, an being called through exec() (or something equivalent)

or

B) Straight PHP Code.

Given that all code is equally coded in both C++ and PHP.

Did a test:
this is the C++

```
Document Length:        100000 bytes
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   0.139 seconds
Complete requests:      10
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1001550 bytes
HTML transferred:       1000000 bytes
Requests per second:    71.76 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       27.872 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       13.936 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          7018.29 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

This is the PHP:

```
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   4.115 seconds
Complete requests:      10
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1001550 bytes
HTML transferred:       1000000 bytes
Requests per second:    2.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       822.924 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       411.462 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          237.71 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Here are the programs (I did not include MySql code -just wanted to see if the stack creation was quicker with basic code).

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream x;
    //string x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        x << "X";
    }

    cout << x.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100000; ++$i)
{
    $x = $x . "X";
}

echo $x;
```

Don't know if its a fair test using stringsteam...  thoughts?  My thought is, C++ is going to be faster regardless of the new stack instance, and mysql connections.

Edit:

Tested with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //stringstream x;
    string x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        x = x + "X";
    }

    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

and, still quicker!

```
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   0.115 seconds
Complete requests:      10
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1740 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    86.98 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       22.994 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       11.497 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          14.78 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Edit:

Here is the php program that calls the C++ file

```
<?php

echo exec("./test");
```

Comment: Well, why don't you try both and time / profile each?

Comment: Maintaining a DB connection handle tied to your PHP session is intuitive, I would say that PHP would provide you more immediate access (using a connection layer like PEAR::MDB2 to do it).

Comment: Having worked with a program that did something similar in perl, I can tell you that switching it to a fully native implementation (in python) cut the execution time down from 10 min to < 1 min. For comparison, we were doing ~300 shell calls.

Comment: Done... with the exception of the MySQL.  I think its a safe bet to assume execution of C++ through an exec() is quicker than straight php.

Comment: Use a normal `std::string` with `+=`, because `x.str()` creates a new string out of the buffer, skewing the real time it takes. :P Aside from that, isn't the SQL part the important one?! Also, did you just execute the C++ code as is or with `exec`?

Comment: I tried with a string also.  I used an exec() through PHP, posting the code text1.php

Comment: Well, considering a basic string test is quicker, I am pretty sure everything will be quicker.  Worst case scenario - the Mysql executes slower, but all the other code around it executes faster.  Will try tomorrow with Mysql.

Comment: 2.43 requests per second with php, vs. 70+ requests per second with C++ running through a PHP exec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's see. Let's fire up a shell, pass it some arguments, which fires up another app, which loads a series of .so libraries, and THEN connects to mysql, does stuff, then has to return a potentially huge lump of output via printf() or equivalent, which then has to be fed back to PHP, parsed as plain text, torn apart, and then turned into some kind of coherent structure.

And this would be faster than doing the query within MySQL and getting the data directly into a PHP structure?

Maybe you should test it...

Comment: I was hoping someone had already did this, I'll wait a couple days just in case, and then start... I'll report my work back here.

Comment: There's no such thing as getting the data directly into a PHP structure. Behind the scenes, all those stuff are still going on.

Comment: @Pacerier: If you think that's how PHP is talking to mysql, I suggest you go study the source code. It may be loading .so's (though generally mysql is compiled in), but it is NOT using printf and text parsing to get data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're handling hundreds of read/writes per second, the difference will very likely be be close to negligible, if extant at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you patch your compliled C++ code in as PHP extension, then yes it would make sense. But unless you are doing significant calculations on the result data with C/C++ it's not faster than executing it as PHP scripting code.

You are more likely to see the performance increase if you optimize/denormalize your database scheme instead, or use the query asynchronously (issue mysql_query at start of script, do something else, and only mysql_fetch_assoc when the mysqld server had a few milliseconds to prepare the result sets).